# How to implement recyclerView which can be scrolled vertically as well as horizontally simultaneously?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How do I implement layout like JioTv during Android development in which one can scroll vertically viewing list of TV channels along with their program and also it can be scrolled horizontally but this time name of TV channel remain fixed? [ScreenShot from jioTv App is attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zsSp.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement RecyclerView inside RecyclerView
And the adapter of the main recyclerView pass the list of data to the adapter per row

Here is an example
[image: Main fragment]

This is the main adapter

```
   class HistoryMainAdapter(val historyMainList: List<HistoryMainResponse.HistoryBean>, val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<HistoryMainAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): HistoryMainAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.history_main_item, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        var current = historyMainList[position]

        holder.history_main_level_value.text = EmojiCompat.get().process(current.level.toString())


        val adapter = HistoryPerLevelAdapter(current.submissions!!, context)
        holder.history_recyclerview.adapter = adapter


    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return historyMainList.size
    }

    class ViewHolder(v: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {
        var history_main_level_value: TextView = v.findViewById(R.id.history_main_level_value)
        var history_recyclerview: RecyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.history_recyclerview)
    }
}
```

XML : history_main_item

[image: Main item]

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView32"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/level_text"
        android:textColor="#ff4a4a4a"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.text.emoji.widget.EmojiTextView
        android:id="@+id/history_main_level_value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:textColor="#ff4a4a4a"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView32"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView32"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView32"
        tools:text="1" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/history_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView32"
        tools:listitem="@layout/history_main_level_item" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is the child adapter

```
class HistoryPerLevelAdapter(val historyMainList: List<HistorySubmissionsBean>, val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<HistoryPerLevelAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): HistoryPerLevelAdapter.ViewHolder {
    val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.history_main_level_item, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(v)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val current = historyMainList[position]

    holder.history_challenge_title.text = EmojiCompat.get().process(current.name!!)

    Picasso.with(context).load(Uri.parse(BASE_URL + current.video!!.thumbnail + tokenForImage)).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(holder.history_challenge_image)
    holder.history_submission_count.text = current.number_of_submissions.toString()

    if (current.score != null) {
        holder.history_submission_point.text = current.score.toString() + "pt"
        holder.history_submission_point.visibility = View.VISIBLE

    } else {
        holder.history_submission_point.visibility = View.GONE
    }

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        mySupportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.without_bottom_bar, HistorySubmissionsForChallengeFragment.newInstance(current._id), HistorySubmissionsForChallengeFragment::class.java.simpleName)
                .addToBackStack(HistorySubmissionsForChallengeFragment::class.java.simpleName)
                .commit()
    }


}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return historyMainList.size
}

class ViewHolder(v: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {
    var history_challenge_title: TextView = v.findViewById(R.id.history_challenge_title)
    var history_challenge_image: ImageView = v.findViewById(R.id.history_challenge_image)
    var history_submission_count: TextView = v.findViewById(R.id.history_submission_count)
    var history_submission_point: TextView = v.findViewById(R.id.history_submission_point)
}}
```

XML : history_main_level_item

[image: Row item]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView3"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/history_challenge_image"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView17"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/scrim" />

            <android.support.text.emoji.widget.EmojiTextView
                android:id="@+id/history_challenge_title"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:text="T-Test (Without the ball)" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/history_submission_count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/submission_times"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cardView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView3"
        tools:text="2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/history_submission_point"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/points_icon"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/history_submission_count"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView3"
        tools:text="2 pts" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

i work on a similiar project as the one you provided in the screenshot, what we use are actually nested RecyclerViews in this way:

- We have a vertical RecyclerView, each item is a **Row** that represents a channel
- Each **Row** is actually an horizontal RecyclerView, each item is a **Box** which represents the program
- Each **Box** has a width according to the program duration in ms

Sorry but i can't provide an example as it would be A LOT of files/code. I hope this helps.